# What are the recommended approaches for generating routes in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, spring-mvc

What are the recommended approaches for generating routes in a java-based Spring MVC webapp? I'd like to avoid hard-coding paths throughout the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about paths RequestMappings etc. 
In my application I have a single class with with a bunch of `public static final` constants that I reference in the @RequestMapping annotations.

So the constants might look like this:

```
public class Pages {
  public static final String FOO_URL "foo/foo.action"
  public static final String FOO_VIEW "test/foo"

  public static final String BAR_URL "bar/bar.action"
  public static final String BAR_VIEW "test/bar"
}
```

then inside your controller you'd reference them like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value=Pages.FOO_URL, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleFoo(Model model) {
      return Pages.FOO_VIEW;
    }
```

They're easy to change as they're all in one place.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a code sample of what that would look like.

Comment: how do you handle value substitution? Do you use static methods on your Pages class? ie: Page.urlFor(page) to generate /pages/1 where the page id was 1?

Comment: In our app, we don't have a need to do this - all of the pages have unique names. looking at the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-advanced) I can't see a requirement for something that changes - perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score -1):

You say you'd like to avoid hard-coding paths throughout the application, but typically all the controllers (and thus all the url mappings) reside in one directory. For example if you have a maven structure they'll be someplace like src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/web/controllers/. Do you envision yourself ever asking the question, "Just where did I put the url mapping for the /myapp/v1/search endpoint?", and not being able to figure out that it's in /src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/web/controllers/V1SearchController.java?

Also once you choose the urls they're pretty much fixed since they represent an interface with clients, and changing them probably means breaking backward compatibility.

Not that I think a class with a bunch of static final Strings is all that bad, I just think it's mostly unnecessary.

Comment: I am mostly interested in the conventions used to generate the URL in the app. The Rails framework has done a great job here. For example, pages_path would generate "/pages/" and page_path(page) would generate "/pages/1". To add query params you could add them like so, page_path(page, :foo => 2, :bar => 3) which would generate "/pages/1?foo=2&bar=3". I find that convention more readable, discoverable, and less error-prone than hard-coding paths and building up URLs yourself. Here's to hoping some convention or library besides manual string concatenation exists.

Comment: You don't change the URLs, obviously... Having all the routes in one place makes it easy for a new developer to view the structure of your web app in one place and not having to open up a dozen controllers in their editor.

Comment: That's true, I usually solve that with a README or other docs but a file with a bunch of constants works too.